# как сделать при увиличени одного блока чтобы второй блок уменьшался?

Tags: css

Как сделать плавающий div при котором если Город выдавливает Логин то он должен уменьшится не съежая вниз за пределы родительского блока

```css
#conteiner{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#one{
    width: auto;
    max-width: auto;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 2px 5px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    float: left;
}

#two{
    width: auto;
    max-width: 150px;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 2px 2px;
    /*border: 1px solid #1e90ff;*/
    color: #1e90ff;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}

#avatar{
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #ff5500;
    float: right;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteiner">
    <div id="one">Город</div>
    <div id="avatar">img</div>
    <div id="two">Логин</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Если название города длинное и логин длинный то город должен уменьшить логин при этом логин обрезается с добавлением многоточия

Comment: Первое что вам советую - откажитесь от `float`, их давно не используют.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `flex`, как рекомендовал @Oliver Patterson

```css
#conteiner {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  gap: 4px;
  padding: 3px;
}

#one {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex: 0 1 auto;  
}


#two { 
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid #1e90ff;
  color: #1e90ff;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#avatar {
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ff5500;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  flex: 0 0 44px;
}
```

```html
<div id="conteiner">
  <div id="one">Город</div> 
  <div id="two">Логин</div>
  <div id="avatar">img</div>
</div>
<div id="conteiner">
  <div id="one">Город Длиннннннный Оченьььььььь</div> 
  <div id="two">Логин</div>
  <div id="avatar">img</div>
</div>
<div id="conteiner">
  <div id="one">Город Длиннннннный Оченьььььььь</div> 
  <div id="two">Логин Длиннннннный Оченьььььььь</div>
  <div id="avatar">img</div>
</div>
<div id="conteiner">
  <div id="one">Город</div> 
  <div id="two">Логин Длиннннннный Оченьььььььь</div>
  <div id="avatar">img</div>
</div>
```

Comment: не совсем то что нужно но близко. Как должно быть:  img с права зафиксирован, с лева Город не должен обрезаться если Логин его выдавливает. Обрезается только Логин. Логин должен прижаться к img и не уходить в сторону Города если Город уменьшается

Comment: position не подходит. Если применить это свойство то блок "Город" наезжает на блок "Логин" при этом текст в блоке "Логин" не обрезается

Comment: @Ruslan, подправил код.

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно